# Django management command without working db connection

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

I have a number of projects that use the following configuration model:

`settings.py` includes default configuration and config specifications, mainly used for development purposes.
The default settings (including db settings) can be overridden by external configuration files, usually defined by admins for the various environments they manage. In order to ease the admins, I have written a management command and packaged separately, which adds the option to create example configuration files based on the default configuration in `settings.py`

Trying to run the command without the possibility for successful db connection, however, raises `django.db.utils.OperationalError`.

How can I make the command work without db connection, as it does not need one and normally when the command is needed, most probably the db connection is not configured properly.

`settings.DATABASES != {}` as there are the default db settings.

*Django 1.10.6, Python 3.5.3*

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.can_import_settings

Comment: Thanks, `requires_system_checks = False` got the job done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do `requires_system_checks = False`

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    requires_system_checks = False
    ...
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        #rest of code
```

For more [info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.requires_system_checks)

Comment: I am just wondering, which default commands require a db conneciton and which do not, is this documented?

Comment: This does not work for me in Django 2.2.3. I still get `OperationalError: could not connect to server: No route to host`